# Nutch 1.2 (crawl or parse) mp3

Tags: solr, mp3, nutch

I have a question about Nutch v1.2.

Can someone explain to me how I can go about crawling/parsing an MP3 and indexing the result into Solr 1.4.

Is there a specific plugin I can use to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a parse-mp3 plugin available with Nutch for parsing out the headers of MP3 audio files.

For a complete list of Nutch Plugins, checkout [Plugin Central](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/PluginCentral)

Comment: but I think mp3-parser plugin removed from version 1.1 in version 1.2 their is something called tika-parser but the problem that nutch can't get mp3 urls and if i put the urls inside seed file it nust download mp3 to parse so if their any chance to make it on the fly parser.

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot they removed it after 0.9.